# SQL Server 2000 : List of tables ordered from by number of referenced tables

Tags: sql-server-2000

Is there any way in SQL Server 2000 to get a list of tables ordered by dependency? I need it for insert order in empty data base.

I can't turn off constraints, so I'm stuck with this solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this function is a good starting point. The original source is lost in the sands of time, but I picked it up from [Uri Dimant](http://dimantdatabasesolutions.blogspot.ca/2007/08/foreign-key-dependency.html).

Normally I don't copy linked content wholesale, but this looks like it will benefit everyone by being here (I've edited a few typos).

---

> Some time ago I was asked to truncate lots of tables in client's
>   database. As such, all those tables have FK and PK dependency. You get
>   the error like that if you run TRUNCATE TABLE Categories in Northwind
>   database as an example.
>
> ```
> --Cannot truncate table 'Categories' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint.
> ```
>
> So , there is no such great problem as you know the database structure
>   and can easily indentify parent-child tables. But what if you don't?
>   I'd like to show the function (sadly, I don't remember by whom it is
>   written) that returns the tables ordered by its level. Level 0 means
>   that it is a referenced table and should be truncated last.
>
> ```
> CREATE VIEW VFKs
> AS
>
> SELECT
> FK.TABLE_SCHEMA AS child_table_schema,
> FK.TABLE_NAME AS child_table_name,
> PK.TABLE_SCHEMA AS parent_table_schema,
> PK.TABLE_NAME AS parent_table_name
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS AS RC
> JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK
> ON RC.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
> AND RC.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
> JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK
> ON RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = PK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
> AND RC.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME
> GO
>
> CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fn_get_tree_of_tables()
> RETURNS @tree TABLE
> (
> table_schema SYSNAME NOT NULL,
> table_name SYSNAME NOT NULL,
> lvl INT NOT NULL,
> PRIMARY KEY(table_schema, table_name)
> )
> AS
> BEGIN
>
> DECLARE @lvl AS INT
> SET @lvl = 0
>
> -- top level tables
> INSERT INTO @tree
> SELECT DISTINCT
> parent_table_schema,
> parent_table_name,
> @lvl
> FROM VFKs AS P
> WHERE NOT EXISTS
> (SELECT *
> FROM VFKs AS C
> WHERE C.child_table_schema = P.parent_table_schema
> AND C.child_table_name = P.parent_table_name)
>
> WHILE @@rowcount > 0
> BEGIN
>
> SET @lvl = @lvl + 1
>
> -- non top level tables
> INSERT INTO @tree
> SELECT DISTINCT
> child_table_schema,
> child_table_name,
> @lvl
> FROM VFKs AS C
> JOIN @tree AS P
> ON P.table_schema = C.parent_table_schema
> AND P.table_name = C.parent_table_name
> AND lvl = @lvl - 1
> WHERE NOT EXISTS
> (SELECT *
> FROM @tree AS T
> WHERE T.table_schema = C.child_table_schema
> AND T.table_name = C.child_table_name)
>
> END
>
> SET @lvl = 0
>
> -- tables with no fks
> INSERT INTO @tree
> SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, @lvl
> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS TB
> WHERE NOT EXISTS(
> SELECT *
> FROM @tree AS TR
> WHERE TB.TABLE_SCHEMA = TR.table_schema
> AND TB.TABLE_NAME = TR.table_name)
> AND
> TB.TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
>
> RETURN
>
> END
> GO
> ```
>
> Here's the results of an invocation of the function in Northwind:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM dbo.fn_get_tree_of_tables() AS T
> ORDER BY lvl
>
> table_schema table_name lvl
> ------------ ----------------------------------- ---
> dbo Categories 0
> dbo CustomerDemographics 0
> dbo Customers 0
> dbo Employees 0
> dbo Region 0
> dbo Shippers 0
> dbo Suppliers 0
> dbo Products 1
> dbo Territories 1
> dbo Orders 1
> dbo CustomerCustomerDemo 1
> dbo Order Details 2
> dbo EmployeeTerritories 2
> ```